# Im trying to compile an open source game using CMake

Tags: cmake

Im not really good at CMake and stuff, but i want to compile a game called "Open Hexagon"

I tried following the tutorial here:
https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVOpenHexagon/wiki/Building-Instructions but i had trouble on step 5 where it says:

"Execute the build script: sh ./build.sh"

So i tried running that command, and it came with an error saying:

`'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

it does the same with "open_distro_window.bat"

[I even tried this, but it didnt work (i did this several times)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jMj0.png)

Please help me

Comment: I just dont know how to run it, every time when i run it on cmd it says that its "not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Please, post (add to the question post) the **exact error message** which you got. And please consult [ask] about the proper way of creating a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thats literally the error i got on cmd, 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: So, you are in the Windows shell and it seems that you execute the previous steps wrong. Please, [edit] the question post and update information about your problem: with **exact** steps you have performed and with exact error message. In the current form your **question post** is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, i edited it, and i made sure i didnt witness any errors that i forgot to put it here

Comment: The step 3 in the tutorial is about opening MinGW shell. How **exactly** have you performed this step? It allows at least two ways: running `open_distro_window.bat` or using Git Bash.

Comment: I first installed MinGW and CMake, Then i copied the git repo, And then i ran into the problem that i thought was involving CMake, there was no way it couldnt

Comment: I asked you about the step 3, but you answered about the step 1 (installing MinGW), the step 2 (installing CMake) and the step 4 (git clone). Don't you find this conversation strange?

Comment: Yes i did run open_distro_window.bat, and typed the command in it, but it still told me it was an invalid command